# Laravel Maatwebsite Export to excel not working

Tags: php, excel, laravel, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel

I'm using Laravel 5.6 with Laravel-Maat Excel version 3.1. Even though i have referred official documentation but still Facing lot of problems while exports data to excel.

Below is the link of that particular docs from git [Click Here to view](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel)

I'm trying to export some data to excel file.But i'm not getting work also their are no errors displayed.

Below is my code

```
php artisan make:export StudentAttendanceExport --model=Models\Student\StudentAttendenceModel
```

File `App\Exports\StudentAttendanceExport`

```
    <?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\Models\Student\StudentAttendenceModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;

class StudentAttendanceExport implements FromCollection
{
    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */
    public function collection()
    {
        return StudentAttendenceModel::all();
    }
}
```

in my controller `Reports\ReportsFormProcessController`

```
  namespace App\Http\Controllers\Reports;

  use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie;
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
  use App\Models\Student\StudentAttendenceModel;
  //EXCEL
  use App\Exports\StudentAttendanceExport;
  use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel; 

    class ReportsFormProcessController extends Controller {
          public function __construct() {
                  parent::__construct();
          }     

            protected function processStdAttendance($data) {
                return Excel::download(new StudentAttendenceModel, 'users.xlsx');
            }

   }
```

IN THE ABOVE LINK THEY SAID THAT `Find your users.xlsx in your downloads folder!` BUT IN WHICH PATH IS HAVE SEARCHED ALL DIRCTORIES BUT STILL DIDN'T FIND IT.

### THANKS IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `StudentAttendanceExport` insted of `StudentAttendenceModel`

```
protected function processStdAttendance($data) {
         return Excel::download(new StudentAttendanceExport, 'users.xlsx');
         //return Excel::download(new StudentAttendenceModel, 'users.xlsx');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Hi Dhruv Raval requesting to provide solution for my question [QUESTION LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53778681/laravel-excel-html-to-excel-conversion-not-working) **THANKS IN ADVANCE**